# Validate elements (jquery repeater)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm working on an e-commerce project that uses jquery repeater in the wizard. I need to loop through the elements of the input to make my validations. Here is my input form code.

```
<button data-repeater-create type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm icon-btn ml-2 mb-2 float-right">
    <i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i>
</button> 
<div data-repeater-list="group">
    <div data-repeater-item class="d-md-flex mb-2">
        <div class="form-group mr-1">
           <input type="text" class="mt-0 form-control form-control-sm" id="sku" name="sku" placeholder="sku">
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

It comes in the browers elements like this,

```
<input type="text" class="mt-0 form-control form-control-sm" id="sku" name="group[0][sku]" placeholder="sku">
```

you can see, its like an array. So I need to get all these elements and validated all. For other field validation I have use

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

can I use this for the those field?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have same problem.  can you share the solution ?

Comment: I have removed the whole process could not find the solution for that.